# How can I get the callable method in a Trait?

Tags: php, laravel, function, methods, traits

I have this trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait PageConfigTrait {

    public function getFormAction()
    {
        return ""; // I want to return 'edit'
    }

}
```

and this controller using the Trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Traits\PageConfigTrait;

class BillTypeController extends Controller
{
    use PageConfigTrait;

    public function index()
    {
     //
    }

    public function edit()
    {
        echo $this->getFormAction();
    }    
}
```

What I need to return 'edit' on getFormAction method on my Trait?

I'm using Laravel.

Thank you

Comment: Just use `echo __FUNCTION__;` in your `edit()`-method, if it's the name of that method you want? Or even `echo 'edit';` since you already know what method it's in? If that's not what you're asking, what exactly are you trying to do/solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using PHP predefined constants.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait PageConfigTrait {

    public function getFormAction($caller)
    {
        return $caller; 
    }

}
```

and then you can call it like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Traits\PageConfigTrait;

class BillTypeController extends Controller
{
    use PageConfigTrait;

    public function index()
    {
     //
    }

    public function edit()
    {
        echo $this->getFormAction(__FUNCTION__);
    }    
}
```

If you don't want to pass anything around, you can use `debug_backtrace();` to do something like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait PageConfigTrait {

    public function getFormAction()
    {
        $trace = debug_backtrace();
        $caller = $trace[1];

        return $caller['function'];
    }

}
```

Then you can use it like you wanted in the code above.

Resource: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: The first will return `getFormAction` and the second will return `PageConfigTrait::getFormAction`. Those magic constants returns the function/method names for the function/method they are written in, not the caller. They should rather skip calling that method and place the `__FUNCTION__` directly in the `edit()`-method instead if they want that name.

Comment: Works if I pass `__FUNCTION__` like parameters to the Trait method, but I dont know.. was weird

Comment: Yes, if I pass using parameters, workd well..

Comment: Yes, that should work, but it makes zero sense to call a method, passing a value just to have it returned back :-p Completely pointless and unnecessary, as it's currently written.

Comment: You can use this if you don't want to pass anything to it: `debug_backtrace()`.

Comment: @Hermus please see my update to the answer.

Comment: Thank you @M.Eriksson for helping us to :muscle: